# SQL query to count events from time periods in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (Event) that tracks events. Each event has a eventTime field. I want to get how many events occurred between time A and time B, how many events occurred between time C and time D, etc. I want each of these counts to be different (i.e. I want a distinct count for each time period). Is there a way to do this with one SQL query? Right now I've been doing something like:

```
select count(ID) from Event where eventTime >= timeA and eventTime <= timeB
```

and I've just been doing that for each period. It takes a while when I have to make five separate queries though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: mysql (i guess comments have to be more than 15 characters..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(eventTime between timeA and timeB) as AB_count,
       sum(eventTime between timeC and timeD) as CD_count                   
from Event
```

Comment: awesome--so does that mean that sum just counts the instances if the field isn't an integer?

Comment: `eventTime between timeA and timeB` returns a boolean value. In MySQL this is `0` or `1`. You can sum up the `true (1)` values using `SUM`. This won't work for MSSQL. There you would have to use a `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a table DateRanges with StartDate and EndDate columns allowing datetimes

```
+-----------+---------+
| StartDate | EndDate |
+-----------+---------+
| A         | B       |
| C         | D       |
+-----------+---------+

Select
  d.StartDate,
  d.EndDate,
  Sum(Case When e.EventTime >= d.StartDate And e.EventTime < d.EndDate Then 1 Else 0 End) as EventCount
From
  DateRanges d
    Cross Join
  Event e
Group By
  d.StartDate,
  d.EndDate
```